# How Do I fix my particular broken package system?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

So I'm having a bit of trouble with my **Ubuntu 13.10** installation. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I did to break it, I think it had something to do with an update not finishing. Anyway, When I got to check for updates or try and install a package I get the following errors:

**Updating Software:**

THE PACKAGE SYSTEM IS BROKEN
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

**Installing a package from the repos (in this case compiz, for the sake of example):**

```
dj@ThetaDome:~$ sudo apt-get install compiz
[sudo] password for dj: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
compiz is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: ca-certificates (>= 20121114) but it is not going to be 
installed
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 libwww-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 python-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 python3-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is the result of **apt-get -f install**:

```
dj@ThetaDome:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libc6-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 183 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main ca-certificates all 20130610 [183 kB]
Fetched 183 kB in 0s (262 kB/s)         
dpkg: error processing ca-certificates (--configure):
 package ca-certificates is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-httplib2:
 python3-httplib2 depends on ca-certificates; however:
 Package ca-certificates is not installed.
dpkg: error processing python3-httplib2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
 python3-httplib2 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anybody please help me resolve this issue? I'd like to troubleshoot through this problem and keep my installation!

**What happens when you try to remove one of these packages?**

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: ca-certificates (>= 20121114) but it is not going to be installed
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 libwww-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 python-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 python3-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: See : http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: Following your blog's advice I got the following error:

<dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of ca-certificates:
 python-httplib2 depends on ca-certificates.
 libwww-perl depends on ca-certificates.
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl depends on ca-certificates.
 ca-certificates-java depends on ca-certificates (>= 20121114).>

Comment: First try removing all those packages. If that fails, manually remove them and run the "dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ..."

Comment: Same results. Should I just reinstall?

Comment: You changed to `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and removed ca-certificates-java, and all the other packages, then `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ca-certificates-java` , and all the other packages ?

Comment: You have to remove python-httplib2 ,  ca-certificates , ca-certificates-java , and  libwww-perl

Comment: ca-certificates-java and python3-httplib2 weren't in /var/lib/dpkg/info when I tried to remove them. Then, when trying to use dpsk to remove the packages I get the following:

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ca-certificates-java
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of ca-certificates-java:
 openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 depends on ca-certificates-java.

dpkg: error processing ca-certificates-java (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java

Comment: " You have to remove python-httplib2 , ca-certificates , ca-certificates-java , and libwww-perl "


From /var/lib/dpkg/info?

Comment: yes sudo rm python-httplib2* ...  (etc), then dpkg dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ca-certificates-java (etc), then sudo apt-get install -f . You are going to need to remove all those packages and their dependencies to fix apt, you can then try to re-install them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11449/discussion-between-djindisguise-and-bodhi-zazen)

Comment: If you still have this problem:You might be interested in this: http://mergy.org/2013/03/repairing-a-badly-damaged-package-system-in-ubuntu/ If not, Feel free to write up your solution as an answer to this question. Thank you!